# ASP.NET Entity Framework code first decimal in database not null

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

My model classes:

```
public class CostAccouting
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public int CostCategoryId { get; set; }
        public CostCategory CostCategory { get; set; }
}

public class CostCategory
{ 
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Bezeichnung")]
        public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

I use the code-first approach, I don't know why EF creates the column `Total` in the DB as not null.

Comment: if you want nullable then make it nullable in c# side : ``public decimal? Total``

Answer (score 2):

Because you've defined it as `decimal` - that means, you *always* expect a valid, decimal value - so it **cannot** be `null`.

If you want to support `null`, you have to define it in your C# class as `decimal?` (nullable decimal)

```
public class CostAccouting
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal? Total { get; set; }
        public int CostCategoryId { get; set; }
        public CostCategory CostCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a variable Nullable in C#, you must use:

`public decimal? Total { get; set; }`

or

`public <Nullable> decimal Total { get; set; }`